# Can I use Third party Payment Gateway (eg. Paytm, Razorpay) for In-app Purchases and Subscription in my Android App in India ? Please explain

Tags: android, flutter, android-inapp-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase, android-subscriptionmanager

I want to integrate payment gateways like paytm or upi for In-app subscriptions in my Android app. I saw many educational apps do this. But I should give Google their share right ? How to do it the correct way ? I don't know. Please someone help. I appreciate any feedback you can share.

Comment: You are free to use any third party gateways provided the price of product is dynamic. If you offer only one course of fixed price then the app maybe rejected saying you need to add google iap. Educational apps have multiple creators who are free to set the price for their course ao adding iap here is difficult. And hence it gets approved.